# PHP cli session warnings

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Is there any possibility to disable session warnings being displayed when php cli script is run? Without modyfing php.ini of course. I need to have clean output of this script. Script is not run as Apache or Root. In php.ini there is an session.auto_start enabled.

I've got following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_p6tpcdkpupelvho22qrkm699g4, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_p6tpcdkpupelvho22qrkm699g4, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who are you running this as? Are you using sessions in your script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite simple, don't try to open the session in CLI mode.  It won't work for multiple reasons.  So, you could do 2 things (depending on how "dirty" of a hack you wanted):

```
if (!isset($argc)) {
    //Not from CLI
    session_start();
}
```

Or, set the session path to something writable (like `/tmp`) if via cli:

```
if (isset($argc)) {
    session_save_path('/tmp');
}
```

But I'd suggest not suppressing all errors (`error_reporting(0)`) because it will make debugging and telling when something went wrong so much harder...  I'd also suggest not using `@` to suppress errors (simply because I think you should avoid errors instead of suppressing them)

Comment: Doens't help. Please remember that there is session autostart enabled in php.ini. I can't disable it.

Comment: Still getting one warning. Looks like we solved first warining but second one (when session is saved) is displayed again) PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_k2hb6dulnlpcp0gru1vuifho61, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: How can I remember if autostart is enabled?  This is the first you mentioned it...

Comment: session_save_path('/tmp'); doesn't seem to work. Session path is not changed by this command for some reason.

Comment: How are you running the script in CLI? ircmaxell is right, just make sure the session is not started: `php -d session.auto_start=Off yourscript.php`

Comment: Or change session.save_path there: `php -d session.save_path=/foo your script.php`.

Comment: php -d session.save_path=/foo your script.php This is an excelent solution. Works great! Cheers!